# Gesture to minimize window in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, window-manager, gestures

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Shell chosen as Desktop Manager.

I'm getting used to how the windows are resized as they are dragged on some edge of the screen (e.g. maximized when dragged on the top, split by half horizontally and right-aligned when dragged on the right ecc), but I'd really like a similar way to minimize the windows when dragged on the bottom, for example.

I know this is possible with a custom shortcut, but, I'd like to do that with just a mouse. So, is it possible? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try Easystroke. Easystroke allows users to create custom mouse gestures so you could simply make a gesture to minimize all windows or the current window or whatever. [This blog post](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/get-mac-like-gesture-support-for-ubuntu/) talks a little about it. There is also more information from the tips/tricks and [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki/Documentation) from the developer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to minimize the window when dragging it on the bottom edge, not with a mouse gesture.